# Bootstrap 4 Carousel responsive design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I've built a page using bootstrap 4. I've added a Carousel with 4 items.
You can see it here: [Landing-Page with Bootstrap 4](http://ovalmartini.bplaced.net/bw/index.php)

And here is the Problem: when loading is finished, you'll have some space over the edge. I will say, that you can scroll to the right side and there is more space, that shouldn't.

What I've tried to fix it:

- removing slide buttons
- using other typs of the carousel
- changing pictures/resizing them
- commented out other elements like divs and navs, except the carousel
- tried other browsers (firefox, chrome, safari)

I hope, it's not a bug.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please **[read how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and 
[what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Remember that questions should be helpful to future readers. Please post the relevant code in the question instead of linking to external sites that may change over time.

Comment: All rows in bootstrap should be placed inside of a container and all col's should be placed in a row, the reason for the extra space is because you have a row outside of a container.  You should always follow bootstraps markup tree.  And word to the wise you should avoid nesting rows, you have a couple of instances of this on your page as well.

Comment: @SteveK thanks a lot. It was my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not appear because of the margins of any row ( as suggested in your accepted answer ) but because some of the rows are not nested inside `containers`.

See here in the docs [grid system bs4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And also here [bs4 containers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/) where it clearly states that `Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are required when using our default grid system.`

*In short the padding of the `containers` counteract the negative margins of the `rows` that in turn counteract the paddings of the `columns`*

**SOLUTION**

Any top-level `row` you have, you should wrap it inside a `container`, in your case you should use `container-fluid`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by looking at the element #ausbildung (between container and jumbotron).

Its width is 30px bigger than it should!

Try to remove the margins on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="ausbildung" class="row" style="height: 50px;"></div>
```

Bootstrap `.row` classes use negative margins to account for child elements that contain padding by default. Override the .row styling with

```
.row {
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

and the space and horizontal scrollbar should disappear. Bear in mind if you use .row elsewhere with Bootstrap col's that you may have to adjust your col's accordingly.